# How should I use my script to show an alert?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, alert

Hi I started Using jsp today and I'm trying to code a simple login jsp page.

Right now I'm trying to show an alert when there is no success login.

here is my jsp page

```
 <body contenteditable="false">
    <p><%= request.getAttribute(Constants.ERROR)%></p>
    <script>
        if (!$(<%= request.getAttribute(Constants.ERROR)%>).isEmptyObject()) {
            alert("Veuillez confirmer mot de passe et le username");
        }

    </script>
    <!-- Static container -->
    <div class="login-wrap">
        <div class="login-html">
            <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked="" contenteditable="false"><label contenteditable="false" for="tab-1" class="tab">Se connecter </label>
            <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up" contenteditable="false" ><label contenteditable="false" for="tab-2" class="tab">S'inscrire</label>
            <div class="login-form">

                <div class="sign-in-htm">
                    <form action="./UserConnect" name="login">
                    ....
                    </form>
```

here is my servlet UserLogin :

```
@WebServlet(name = "UserConnect", urlPatterns = {"/UserConnect"})
public class UserConnect extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
private UtilisateurFacadeLocal utilisateurFacade;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter(Constants.USERNAME);
    String password = request.getParameter(Constants.PASSWORD);        
    String email ="";

    boolean doLogin = utilisateurFacade.doLogin(username, password, email);
    System.out.println("do login "+doLogin);
    if (doLogin) {
        response.sendRedirect("https://www.google.fr");
    }else{
       request.setAttribute(Constants.ERROR, "login ou mot de passe incorrecte");
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
       requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

`

my `<p>` is well showing the message but there is no alert what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your jquery function with $(document).ready

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       if (!$(<%= request.getAttribute(Constants.ERROR)%>).isEmptyObject()) {
        alert("Veuillez confirmer mot de passe et le username");
       }
    });


</script>
```